# Oracle Sql: Case When and Decode

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the error "Missing Keyword" for this query.

The purpose of this query is to find the Zone designation. Example: If COLUMN1 is 'Lab', and COLUMN2 is 'Reg1', then create a new column called CollectionZone with the text of 'Zone1'. Or if COLUMN1 is 'Lab', and COLUMN2 is 'Reg2', then create a new column called CollectionZone with the text of 'Zone2'. Sequence will continue for Reg3, Zone 3, etc.

I am uncertain of why there is an error message. Perhaps the error is because I don't know how to End the Case statement. Any thoughts about how to change the query? Thanks!

```
Select
Case When COLUMN1 In ('Lab') Then
Decode (COLUMN2, 'Reg1', 'Zone1', 'Reg2', 'Zone2', 'DefaultZone') CollectionZone
From Test_Table
;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `END` for the `CASE` statement. Documentation and examples are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

```
Select
    Case 
        When COLUMN1 In ('Lab') 
        Then Decode(COLUMN2, 'Reg1', 'Zone1', 'Reg2', 'Zone2', 'DefaultZone') END CollectionZone
From Test_Table;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, a `case` statement needs an `end`

```
CASE WHEN column1 = 'Lab'
     THEN DECODE( column2, 'Reg1', 'Zone1', 'Reg2', 'Zone2', 'DefaultZone')
 END CollectionZone
```

I would strongly suspect, though, that you're missing an `ELSE` in your `CASE`.  If `column1` is anything other than `Lab`, then your query would return `NULL`.  Is that really what you want?  Or do you really want `'DefaultZone'`?

From a practical standpoint, though, I'm hard-pressed to imagine why you'd use both a `CASE` and a `DECODE`.  It would seem to make much more sense to use one or the other.

```
CASE WHEN column1 = 'Lab'
     THEN CASE column2
               WHEN 'Reg1' THEN 'Zone1' 
               WHEN 'Reg2' THEN 'Zone2'
               ELSE 'DefaultZone'
           END
 END CollectionZone
```

Of course, if you these are actual values and not just examples, you'd really want to do a bit of string manipulation to get the numeric piece off of your `Column2` value and use that to construct your `Zone` value.

Answer (score 2):

I am an advocate of just using `case` and not using `decode()`.  `case` is ANSI standard and more powerful.  You can do this with one level of case as:

```
Select (Case When COLUMN1 In ('Lab') and COLUMN2 = 'Reg1' THEN 'Zone1'
             When COLUMN1 In ('Lab') and COLUMN2 = 'Reg2' THEN 'Zone2'
             When COLUMN1 In ('Lab') and COLUMN2 = 'Reg3' THEN 'Zone3'
             ELSE 'DefaultZone'
        end) as CollectionZone
From Test_Table;
```

Note that this behaves a little differently from your version, because the result is never `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = 'Lab' AND COLUMN2 = 'Reg1' THEN 'Zone1'
      WHEN COLUMN1 = 'Lab' AND COLUMN2 = 'Reg2' THEN 'Zone2'
      WHEN COLUMN1 = 'Lab' AND COLUMN2 = 'Reg3' THEN 'Zone3'
      --Continue till the combination you want    
      ELSE NULL END) as CollectionZone

      from TestTable
```

Comment: How is this substantially different from Gordon's answer?